# Geodjango with Mysql coordinates/polygons precision

Tags: python, mysql, django, polygon, geodjango

I've created a geodjango database working with MySQL.

My problem is that when I add a new record with a PolygonField and then check 
for a point if it is inside this polygon I get a wrong results (more points then I should have). I use `[Location.objects.filter(shape__contains='POINT(-0.058188 51.504289)')]`  to check for a point inside a polygon shape.

My model is:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    locationId = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    shape = models.PolygonField(null=True, blank=True)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

To add my shape into a database I used:

```
polygon = Polygon(((-0.076406999999999975,51.495287999999995),(-0.076412999999999953,51.495159000000008), …(-0.076406999999999975,51.495287999999995)))
```

Please see this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRSnX.png
Even on the map in geodjango admin we can see that the boarders of this polygon are not in the correct pleace.

I was using a simple python script like this to compare my results with geodjango:
http://geospatialpython.com/2011/01/point-in-polygon.html

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help. Finally I've used a two-phase approach:

** - First step** is to check for a list of results using shape__contains

** - Second step** is to loop through those results and check if a point is inside those polygons using polygon.intersects(locationPoint)

Answer (score 2):

Quote Justin Bronn:

> "MySQL is a crippled spatial database..."

Instead of contains it actually executes bbcontains, and is well known for unreliable results. https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13430

I'd suggest moving to PostgreSQL.
I don't have answer if it's not an option.

Comment: I agree. PostgreSQL is the only serious option. I just moved from mysql to postGIS for the same purpose and it's not very difficult to install/manage and query.